# Supporting two incompatible gem versions for a dependency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, rubygems

I have a gem that I use which currently depends on the google-api-client v 0.8x, I'd like to update the gem to support google-api-client v 0.9x.

The Auth between those two is completely different and incompatible.

Is there a way to know which version of the gem dependency is intalled and act accordingly?
So I can add the support for those people who for whatever reason have upgraded the API client whilst continuing to allow people still on the older version to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the version from [`Google::Apis::VERSION`](https://github.com/google/google-api-ruby-client/blob/f650a39e1645358f70837294131d9a08a7a1f3e0/lib/google/apis/version.rb). Declaring the version as a constant in the "gem module" (the module that the rest of gem in nested in) is pretty much standard among gems.

You can extract the version from the gemspec of any installed gem by using `rubygems`. Which can be useful if you don't know how VERSION is nested or even if the gem only specifies the version in the gemspec.

```
require "rubygems"

spec = Gem::Specification::load("google-api-client.gemspec")
puts spec.version
```